# How can I speed up live stream of screen capture with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, vlc

I am attempting to stream the desktop of one computer to another computer on an internal network. I am trying to use ffmpeg on the sending side and VLC on the receiving side. I am using screen-capture-recorder as the video input device. I have been trying the command: `ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -f mpegts udp://host:port` With this command there is a 2-5 second delay on the receiving machine. I need to get the delay down to less than a second.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to reduce the delay?

Comment: Complete ffmpeg console output is missing.

Comment: Are you referring to delay in displaying each video frame (time between when the capture was taken on computer 1 to the time it was displayed on computer 2) or delay in starting the playback (time between running VLC on the receiver and when the video is first displayed)?

Comment: probably want to use an encoder with less latency, or possibly a client with less cacheing/prebuffering https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide